# MySQL data import auto-increment issue

Tags: mysql, import, duplicates, auto-increment

I am attempting to import data into a table that has a field as follows:

`result_id`

This field is set to `AUTO_INCREMENT`, `PRIMARY` and `UNIQUE`.

The data I am importing has information in the `result_id` field that is the same (in places) as the current data in the table.  SQL won't let me import as there are duplicates (which is fair enough).

Is there a way to get SQL to append the data I am importing and not use the duplicate data in `result_id`, basically to continue the number within the SQL field.  The reason I am asking is that I am importing about 25,000 records and I don't want to manually have to remove or alter the `result_id` information from the data being imported.

Thanks,

H.

Comment: If the result_id value can be changed when it is a duplicate then it suggests it isn't meaningful and all could be changed. Would that be possible and easier?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How are you importing your data to MySQL?

If you are using SQL queries/script, then there should be something like `INSERT INTO...`. Open the file in some text editor and replace all `INSERT` by [`INSERT IGNORE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html). This will **ignore** inserting rows with duplicate primary keys. 
Or alternatively if you want to replace older data with same primary keys to that in your import script, then simply use [`REPLACE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replace.html) query in place of `INSERT` query.

Hope it helps...

**[EDIT]**

Since you have Primary key, auto increment. In your table in which you want to import data, add a dummy column say "dummy" and allow it to be NULL. Now, in your import script there will be statement like INSERT INTO  () values (). Now in the list of column names replace "result_id" by "dummy" and execute the script. 
After executing script simply remove "dummy" column from table. Though it is bit dirty and time consuming but will do your work.

Comment: Sorry, not what I'm looking for - where there are duplicates on the `result_id` I still want them important as the actual data is different.